# Symblog error over passing a value with twig

Tags: php, symfony

I'm following the symblog tutorial right now, using Symfony 2.2.2

2.3 has some breaking changes, so I'm using 2.2 to get info on deprecated functions. But to the problem:

After having created the comment form, I got an error saying no route was found for the GET comment:new controller.

That appeared to be an update in Twig, where the following code used to work:

```
{% render 'BloggerBlogBundle:Comment:new' with { 'blog_id': blog.id } %}
```

You must now use:

```
{% render controller('BloggerBlogBundle:Comment:new') with { 'blog_id': blog.id } %}
```

After that, I got another error, stating the following:

> Controller
>   "Blogger\BlogBundle\Controller\CommentController::newAction()"
>   requires that you provide a value for the "$blog_id" argument (because
>   there is no default value or because there is a non optional argument
>   after this one).

As far as I'm aware, `with { 'blog_id': blog.id }` should pass that argument along. But it's not.

The comments for the tutorial are extensive, but nothing mentions this. And I'm not very familiar with twig and symfony, I don't know where else to look for the problem.

EDIT: to be clear, I am calling this controller function from within an already existing twig file, not from inside a PHP file. No route has been defined for it. The action will then call another twig file to include the form element to the page. The tutorial explains this is so the form can be re-used on various parts of the site, removing the need to make a large amount of form elements which basically all do the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the symfony documentation you should use

```
{{ render(controller('BloggerBlogBundle:Comment:new', { 'blog_id': blog.id })) }}
```

Comment: Apparently this is not the correct way to do anymore (see quote from the doc in the answer below)

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/templating.html):

> To include the controller, you'll need to refer to it using an
>   absolute url:

```
{# app/Resources/views/base.html.twig #}

{# ... #}
<div id="sidebar">
    {% render url('latest_articles', { 'max': 3 }) %}
</div>
```

> Since Symfony 2.0.20/2.1.5, the Twig render tag now takes an absolute
>   url instead of a controller logical path. This fixes an important
>   security issue (CVE-2012-6431) reported on the official blog. If your
>   application uses an older version of Symfony or still uses the
>   previous render tag syntax, you should upgrade as soon as possible.

Find the url of the BloggerBlogBundle:Comment:new action in your route file, and use the syntax above. This should work.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Perhaps I should have been more clear: I am not rendering a url, but a small piece of HTML. Just a form element, not an entire page. There is no url for this action in my route file, the tutorial doesn't mention it and it's not shown in the github repo either. The comment below did actually work, even if it's no longer a correct way of working. But what you suggest cannot be implemented, the bundle isn't built that way. So I'm taking the other solution for now, unless you can clarify what should be done.